# Deploy Apache Pulsar cluster, on Azure (terraform)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, deployment, terraform, pulsar

I need to create a Pulsar cluster in a completely automatic way. First, the machines are created, then the software is installed. I am looking for such a solution, but the examples available on the internet relate to aws. In the book https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=eYBTEAAAQBAJ there are links to git repo with an example that has been removed (**https://github.com/josep2/pulsar-ias**). Maybe someone has these files, or knows a tutorial about this topic. I'm a beginner in Azure and containers so forgive me if the question is silly.

Comment: you should be able to tweak this https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/fr/deploy-aws/